# A lot of Scala based questions on unanswered section

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, unanswered-questions

I am new to Stack Overflow and I found that a majority of the questions under the 'unanswered' questions category are based on topics related to Scala. Is my observation true? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: Might that be a tag that you're following?

Comment: its not the case actually

Comment: It might be true for *you*, but it depends on what specifically you're looking at. For example, if I just click on "Unanswered" I have exactly one Scala question in the first 150 "newest" results.

Answer (score 3):

Errr. Looking myself, I can just see 889 of 13429 questions unanswered. That is 7% and therefore totally within the range of the other languages:

- C: 8%
- C++: 10%
- C#: 15%
- Clojure: 4%
- Haskell: 3%
- Java: 16%
- Ocaml: 2%
- Python: 12%
- Ruby: 14%

Am I looking at something different?

- Unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala?sort=unanswered&pagesize=15
- All: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala?sort=newest&pagesize=15

? If I use Bart's method to search for unaccepted answers, that gives you 38% unanswered in the case of Java, so certainly there is something wrong with the search algorithm.

Comment: Nah, there's nothing wrong. Unanswered will most likely mean "No accepted or upvoted answer", which is slightly different from what the searches provide.

Comment: More than a half of these 900 unanswered questions, does actually have answers, but not accepted or up-voted. I myself use StackOverflow exclusively to answer Scala questions. My observation is that most unanswered questions concern usage of new Scala features, integration problems, Web frameworks, working with SQL and NoSQL, deploying Scala applications on cloud/mobile platforms. There is enough base of answers concerning general Scala usage, never ever had any problems with those.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search reveals there are at the moment:

- [13,429](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) questions tagged with the [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) tag
- [3,142](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscala%5D%20hasaccepted:no) questions have no accepted answer (23.4%)
- [460](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscala%5D%20answers:0) of those questions have no answer at all (3.4%)

How this compares against other tags I don't know, but 23.4% does seem rather high.

Comment: The [top answerers page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/topusers) says it's 6.6 percent unanswered.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmm, what explains that difference? What counts as "unanswered"? Do upvotes play a role there?

Comment: Recency perhaps? No idea what the queries are behind those numbers.

Comment: In comparison: C has 8% unanswered, C++ 10%, C# 15%, Clojure 4%, Haskell 3%, Java 16%, Ocaml 2%, Python 12%, Ruby 14%. Seems quite high indeed.

Comment: @0__ "Unanswered" by what definition? No accepted answer? Or by the count on the "top answerers" page?

Comment: As far as I know, it's no accepted or up voted answer, [which works out about right](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/95124).

Comment: Data Explorer has [Unanswered Questions by Tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/42823/unanswered-questions-by-tag) that you can run for comparison. It uses the "no accepted or up voted answer" definition that Tim Stone mentioned above to count unanswered questions in a tag.  Scala isn't in the top (bottom?) 50.